# What is wrong with my jQuery and twilio Code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twilio, twilio-php

I went to these two ( [1](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/increase-app-downloads-with-mobile-app-distribution-powered-by-twilio.html) , [2](http://www.apptamin.com/blog/app-download-button/) ) site for one of my projects.
I'm a noob at PHP. So I'm not really sure how to make this work.
I once got a SSL certificate error while trying to test it. My SMS are not getting sent.
I don't get any kind of reply or alert or something when I'm testing it with my HTML.
Please help me if there's any [twilio and PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) expert are out there.
this the form I'm using in HTML

```
<form id="frm" name="frm">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tel">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>
   </div>
   <button class="btn" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My script

```
$("#frm").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post("sendnotifications.php", $("#frm").serialize(),
   function(data){
   if(data.sms_sent == 'OK'){
   alert("Message Sent");
   } else {
   alert("Message Not Sent");
   }
   }, "json");
});
```

and here is my sendnotifications.php file

```
<?php/* Send an SMS using Twilio. You can run this file 3 different ways:


*
 * - Save it as sendnotifications.php and at the command line, run
 * php sendnotifications.php
 *
 * - Upload it to a web host and load mywebhost.com/sendnotifications.php
 * in a web browser.
 * - Download a local server like WAMP, MAMP or XAMPP. Point the web root
 * directory to the folder containing this file, and load
 * localhost:8888/sendnotifications.php in a web browser.
 */

// Step 1: Download the Twilio-PHP library from twilio.com/docs/libraries,
 // and move it into the folder containing this file.
 require "Services/Twilio.php";

// Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
 $AccountSid = "ACexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $AuthToken =  "fafyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

// Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
 $http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
    'https://api.twilio.com',
    array('curlopts' => array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    ))
);

 $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);

// Step 4: Get phone number from the test-sms form
 $phone=$_POST["phoneNumber"];

// Step 5: Create SMS
 $sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(

// Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number
 // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
 "717-xxx-xxxx",

// the number we are sending to - Any phone number
 $phone,

// the sms body
 "Get our app now: http://example.com/ourapp"
 );

// Display a confirmation message on the screen
 $sms_check='OK'; //Use Twilio's callback here
 $return_json = '{"sms_sent":"' . $email_check . '"}';

echo $return_json;
?>
```

Please someone tell me what do I need to change to get my site working.
I have changed the $http in sendnotifications.php after going to the github faq of twilio to prevent the ssl certificate error. What else do I need to do??

**Edit: I have solved the problem using the below code.**

```
    <?php 
// Step 1: Download the Twilio-PHP library from twilio.com/docs/libraries,
// and move it into the folder containing this file.
 require_once "Services/Twilio.php";
// Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
 $AccountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $AuthToken = "04dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 // Twilio REST API version
 $version = "2010-04-01";
// Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
 $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken, $version);
// Step 4: Get phone number from the test-sms form
 $phone=$_POST["phoneNumber"];

try{
$message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
    "From" => "+1xxxxxxxxxx",
    "To" => $phone,
    "Body" => "This code is for testing!",
));
$sms_check='OK';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $sms_check = 'Error';
}
$return_json = '{"sms_sent":"' . $sms_check . '"}';
echo $return_json;
?>
```

But I'm now getting an error in my server..
The SMS is getting sent but this error shows up..

**Error: Could not decode response body as JSON. This likely indicates a 500 server error**

Does anyone know any way of solving this problem.. My website is hosted on altervista.

**Edit I have solved the 500 error**

By replacing the tinyHttp.php file inside "Services/Twilio"with a  edited tinyhttp.php file from github.. The link of the edited github file is in the comment section..

Comment: can you post any errors you are getting, also look in the apache log

Comment: [this is the github link](https://github.com/camuthig/twilio-php/blob/20d4f3c4479c93894866f498e89a0f13cf16d6bf/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php)

Answer (score 2):

Current Issue:

Try this

```
require_once "Services/Twilio.php";
$AccountSid = "ACexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$AuthToken = "fafxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$client = new Services_Twilio($$AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$phone=$_POST["phoneNumber"];

try{
$client->account->messages->sendMessage("+17xxxxxx", $phone, "This code is for testing an android app website!! Get our app now: http://bit.ly/ourapp");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Past Issue:

It looks like you weren't consistent with your variables. `$sid` and `$token` might not be set, you used `$AccountSid` and `$AuthToken` to set your variables. Try this

`$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken, "2010-04-01", $http);`

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I have solved the 500 server error. I'm updating my question..